Proxying with Apache2
I've read many different threads here, read the official manual, but nothing has worked. Here is the problem: I have a website running on port 80, I need to open the website located at http://<server2_IP>/ when accessing http://<server1_IP>/ws/.
I tried to do it using this config:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "/ws" "http://<server2_IP>/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/ws" "http://<server2_IP>/"
</VirtualHost>

But nothing worked and when opening /ws on the main website I get a 404 error.
I don't use the ServerName field, because the website works only in the local network

have you enabled mod_proxy?  sudo a2enmod proxy, sudo a2enmod proxy_http. Aslo , insted of "/ws "  use  "/ws/"

yes, mod_proxy is enabled. Adding / after ws has no effect

What you can see in the apache error log ?

link
Here's the server log. These lines are repeated every time the server is restarted. The access.log is empty

sudo a2enmod http2
sudo a2enmod proxy_http2 ,sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event

I can't turn off mpm_prefork as it is needed for php8.2 which is used on the site

What do you mean by "The access.log is empty"? That means no requests are processed at all. That clearly contradicts your claim that you receive back a 404. Unless you switched off logging or are looking at the wrong log files ...

When I run the cat /var/log/apache2/access.log command it outputs nothing. Regardless of whether I am accessing a working page or a proxied page. At the same time in /var/log/apache2/error.log messages appear steadily. The permissions and owners of these files are the same. I don't know how to disable logging in access.log, the config has LogLevel: warn, but it affects error.log

It's solved - I'm dumb as fk. For some reason the sites were disabled and I was seeing the default apache stub. After a2ensite 000-default.conf everything worked
